# node.js require() cache auto-invalidate

Tags: node.js

I understand that the require cache can be cleared using `delete`, but instead of running delete every time I use an external module, has anyone done a way of detecting that a file is changed (e.g. via modified time?) and only invalidate the cache if it has change?  I.e. instead of:

```
var ext = require(filename);
ext.do_stuff();
delete require.cache[require.resolve(filename)];
```

Something along the lines of:

```
if(PSEUDO_is_file_changed(filename)){
    delete require.cache[require.resolve(filename)];
}
var ext = require(filename);
ext.do_stuff();
```

I'm thinking about something along the lines of `fs.stat` and just keeping track of the `mtime` but the filename path resolution could be problematic...

**EDIT:** This turned out to be easier then I expected... the full path is via `require.resolve(filename)` then use the `fs.statSync` on that.  I just put the `mtime` directly into the cache object:

```
var ext_fn = require.resolve(filename);
var ext_info = fs.statSync(ext_fn);
if (ext_fn in require.cache && require.cache[ext_fn]._x_modtime != ext_info.mtime.getTime()) {
    delete require.cache[ext_fn];
}
var ext = require(filename);
require.cache[ext_fn]._x_modtime = ext_info.mtime.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

### instead of monitoring you can:

if you know when you will change a file, you can send node a POSIX signal
and register a signal handler, that prevents you from having to keep checking.
http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events
just pick the most appropriate one

```
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  watcher.find_modified_files();
});
```

### delete files

> /**
>    * Modules are cached in this object when they are required. 
>    * By deleting a key value from this object, the next require will reload the module.
>    * @type {Object}
>    */
>
> require.cache = {};

so deleting the entry is enough, now all you need to do is to reload the file
you can make some file you require anywhere really and have it export a method that requires the requested resource inside a function call

### now for the reloading and logic

create some module, i named it watcher.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var watchlist = {};

var local_require = function (root, mod) {
    mod = require.resolve(path.join(root, mod));
    fs.stat(mod, function (err, stats) {
        watchlist[mod] = stats.mtime.getTime();
    });
    require(mod);
};

var update = function (path) {
    delete require.cache[path];
    require(path);
};

var find_modified_files = function () {
    Object.keys(watchlist).forEach(function (key) {
        fs.stat(key, function (err, stats) {
            var time = stats.mtime.getTime();
            if (watchlist[key] !== time) {
                watchlist[key] = time;
                update(key);
            }
        });
    });
};

module.exports = {
    require: local_require,
    update: update,
    find_modified_files: find_modified_files
};
```

to use this:

```
var watcher = require('./lib/watcher');
var mod_a = watcher.require(__dirname, './mod-a');
```

you will have to provide the `__dirname`, so require can locate the file relative to the module you import it in, otherwise the file will be searched for relative to the location of the watcher module.

since require is a glboal provided by nodejs itself, and is locked, you cannot change the global require call, so you cannot track all require's made.

### warning

even tho this works, it might not be what you expect from it.

you will need to adopt a special style of interacting with the modules you watch, if you hold an reference to a required module, then, even after its reloaded and removed from memory, your reference will still hold the previous version of that module.

as a result of the references, most of the libraries you will use cannot be reloaded in such a manner.

example:

```
var watcher = require('./lib/watcher');
var mod_a = watcher.require(__dirname, './mod-a');
var applier = function (ref, scoped) {
  return function (arg) {
    return ref.x(scoped, arg);
  }
}
var closure = closure(mod_a, 'piccle me');
closure('test');
```

inside the function returned by the applier the "ref" variable holds the current mod_a
and it will forever hold it, even when mod_a is reloaded, so change your coding style accordingly